# SQL complex dynamic Pivoting 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hi I am trying in SQL Server the pivoting for the following table

```
REFID | COL1 | COL2 | Sequence
1       abc    cde     1
1       lmn    rst     2
1       kna    asg     3
2       als    zkd     2
2       zpk    lad     1
```

I want the output as

```
        REFID | 1COL1 | 2COL1 | 3COL1 |1COL2|2COL2|3COL2
           1    abc     lmn      kna    cde   rst   asg
           2    zpk     als      null   lad   zkd   null
```

The number of columns in the original table are known but the number of rows are not known. Can any one help

Comment: Which version of SQLServer are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include the `sequence` number as part of your column names, then you will still need to unpivot your `col1` and `col2` columns first, then apply the pivot. The difference is that you will concatenate the `sequence` number to your column names created during the unpivot process.

For a known number of values the query would be:

```
select REFID, 
    [1col1], [2col1], [3col1],
    [1col2], [2col2], [3col2]
from 
(
    select REFID, 
        col = cast(Sequence as varchar(10))+ col, value
    from yourtable
    cross apply
    (
        select 'COL1', col1 union all
        select 'COL2', col2
    ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([1col1], [2col1], [3col1],
                [1col2], [2col2], [3col2])
) piv
order by refid;
```

Then if you have an unknown number the dynamic SQL version will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(Sequence as varchar(10))+ col) 
                    from yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                        select 'Col1', 1 union all
                        select 'Col2', 2
                    ) c(col, so)
                    group by Sequence, col, so
                    order by  so, sequence
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT refid, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select REFID, 
                    col = cast(Sequence as varchar(10))+ col, value
                from yourtable
                cross apply
                (
                    select ''COL1'', col1 union all
                    select ''COL2'', col2
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by refid'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```