# How to rename column with prefixes of a result table, the result table is obtained using pivot query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables named `Emp` and `TrainingTable`

- `Emp` columns (`EmpId(PK, int, not null), EmpName(nchar(10), null)`)
- `TrainingTable` columns (`EmpId(FK, int, null), TainingId(int, null), TainingName(nvarchar(50), not null)`)

Code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(TainingId) 
                from TrainingTable
                group by TainingId
                order by TainingId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT EmpName,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select Emp.EmpName, TainingName, TainingId
            from TrainingTable INNER JOIN Emp ON TrainingTable.EmpId = Emp.EmpId
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(TainingName)
            for TainingId in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Now what I want to do is to rename the columns 1,2,3.. with Training1,Traning2,.. and so on..
the result table may change depending on data. columns may increase..

I tried almost every thing .. but not getting the correct way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You need to cast your column Using CAST()

```
        DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Training' + CAST(TainingId AS Varchar(50))) 
                        from TrainingTable
                        group by TainingId
                        order by TainingId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

        set @query = 'SELECT EmpName,' + @cols + ' from 
                 (
                    select Emp.EmpName, 
                           TainingName,
                           col = ''Training'' + cast(TainingId as varchar(10))
                    from TrainingTable 
                    INNER JOIN Emp ON TrainingTable.EmpId = Emp.EmpId
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    max(TainingName)
                    for col in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

        execute(@query)
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408047/sql-complex-dynamic-pivoting-2?rq=1)

Comment: i got error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'Training'."  so i added extra single quote ''Training'' and executed it .. then i got error "Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'x'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'TainingId'."

Comment: yes i tried it but got "Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'x'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'TainingId'"

Comment: @Sonia The error is only due to ''Training'' in query. Try with queotes

Comment: @Sonia I have Updated solution

Comment: Please refer this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408047/sql-complex-dynamic-pivoting-2?rq=1 and make a change. or build your schema in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @VigneshKumar, OP updated your answer with their working code (which I fixed the formatting of), feel free to roll back if there's any problem with that